How To Setup Pi Camera Livestreaming with ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to integrate a raspberry pi camera into my robotic platform running on ROS2 Humble Hawksbill on Ubuntu 22.04. It works fine with all of the built in libraries on the default raspberry pi OS - but I have Ubuntu 22.04 running on the raspberry pi in order for the ROS2 Humble platform to control the robot - and none of the camera libraries are recognized.
Is there any way I can still use the raspberry Pi Camera on Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) with ROS2 humble installed and have the camera functional on this OS. Ideally I am looking to setup livestreaming functionality from the camera to the local network. I'm new to working with this kind of software and haven't worked with Raspberry Pi Cameras before so I appreciate any help I can get!

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B and a Raspberry pi camera model 3 NOIR

If you need me to clarify on something or if you need information please ask!
